# php logs random username and passwords in?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
    //mysql connection
    $com = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("usersystem");
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
      $userName = $_POST['userName'];
      $passWord = $_POST['passWord'];
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT userID FROM tbl_users WHERE userName='$userName' AND passWord='$passWord' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
    //"login success";
      $data = mysql_fetch_array($result,1);
      $_SESSION['userID'] = $data['userID'];
      header("location: dashboard.php");
    }
    else {
      //login failed
      $error = "login failed";
    }
```

I have set up a database in phpMyAdmin, and I have 2 users in my database. However, when I launch my site, I type in the username and password for both user's and it works! But, if I type in random words for both username and passwords it still logs in, I'm very confused. Please help me.

Comment: `if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){` seems wrong for a success check

Answer (score 5):

```
  if(mysql_num_rows($query)==1){
        //"login success";
        $data=mysql_fetch_array($query,0);
        $_SESSION['userID']=$data['userID'];
        header("location:dashboard.php");
        }
```

change the zero to 1 and also dont use mysql_  is deprecated use mysqli or PDO

```
 $query=mysql_query("SELECT userID FROM tbl_users WHERE userName='$userName' AND   passWord='$passWord' limit 1 ", $com);
```

and change this.

Comment: It says "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\goroam\index.php on line 13"

Comment: because your query doesnt return anything

Comment: This solution is technically correct, but `$query` is a very misleading name for the result of a database query. It's like mixing up question and answer. Better call the variable `$result`

Comment: are you sure you have a connection with your databas?

Comment: now it's saying, "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\goroam\index.php on line 13"

Comment: that means somthing went wrong with your query check all details carefully like tables that your selecting etc.

Comment: im getting this now, "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\goroam\index.php on line 10"

Comment: does your database have a password? and are you using one in your script?

Comment: line 10 remove ; at the end of the line

Comment: That means, that `$result` is `FALSE`, because that is the only boolean value, mysql_query() returns. There is an error in your SQL query. Add `if (!$result) die("Database error: " . mysql_error());` to learn more.

Comment: under the mysql_query

Comment: Either you database login fails or "root" has no access to the "usersystem" database. Put `if (!$com) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());` below the `mysql_connect` to check the login.

Answer (score 2):

You are better off with

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)) {
..
```

[**docs**](http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows) :

> The number of rows in a result set on success or FALSE on failure.

Answer (score 0):

`$query` is an empty variable.

Go for

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userID FROM tbl_users WHERE userName='$userName' AND passWord='$passWord' LIMIT 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    //"login success";
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result,0);
    ...
```